# How to display image in gridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datagridview

```
Private Sub sbloadgrd()
    Dim x As String = "select unqid, imgTitle, imgTh from Image_Gallery_AYS"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(Dal.conMain)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = Dal.GettDS(x).Tables(0)
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

I am binding a title and image in a `gridview`, and underneath is how I am saving image in database:

```
Dim obj As New clsAddImageGallery
obj.imgTitle = txtTitle.Text
obj.imgDesc = txtDecs.Text
Dim imgth1 As String = fileuploadimg.PostedFile.FileName
Dim str1 As String() = imgth1.Split(".")
Dim strex1 As String = str1(1)
obj.img = "~/uploads/" + g.ToString() + "." + strex1
Dim imgth3 As String = fileuploadthumb.PostedFile.FileName
Dim str3 As String() = imgth1.Split(".")
Dim strex3 As String = str3(1)
obj.imgTh = "~/uploads/" + g.ToString() + "." + strex3
```

I am getting `img url` instead of a `img`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

  If FileUpload1.PostedFile IsNot Nothing Then

   Dim FileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)



   'Save files to disk

   FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/" & FileName))



   'Add Entry to DataBase

   Dim strConnString As [String] = System.Configuration. _

    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conString"). _

    ConnectionString

   Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)

   Dim strQuery As String = "insert into tblFiles (FileName, FilePath)" _

    & " values(@FileName, @FilePath)"

   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName)

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "images/" & FileName)

   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

   cmd.Connection = con

   Try

     con.Open()

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

   Catch ex As Exception

     Response.Write(ex.Message)

   Finally

     con.Close()

     con.Dispose()

   End Try

  End If

End Sub
```